# How can I find kernel of linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the kernel of linear map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\to \mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ if:
$$f
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    1 & 2 &3\\
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$f
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 3 & 5\\
    3 & 3 &5\\
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$f
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 &1\\
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$f
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 &1\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
and how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by showing that the four $2\times 2$ matrices $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ you know the images under $f$ of form a basis of $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$. Then any $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ can uniquely be expressed as $A = \lambda_1 A_1 + \dots + \lambda_4 A_4$. Using linearity, $f(A)=0$ is equivalent to
$$
\lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_2 \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 3 & 5\\
    3 & 3 & 5
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_3 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_4 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is a linear system of $6$ equations in $4$ variables, but it is rather redundant. It is equivalent to
$$
\lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 2 \\ 3
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_2 \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\ 3 \\ 5
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_3 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 1 \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda_4 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Row reduction yields
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 5 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And hence the solution coefficient vectors are
$$
(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4) \in \operatorname{span}\big((1,-1,1,1)\big).
$$
Thus, the kernel of $f$ is spanned by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix} -
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    1 & 2\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

To find the kernel of a linear map $f:V\to W$ is the same as solving the equation
$
f(x)=0\;. 
$

What you know in your problem are the values of $f(\alpha_k)$ where $\alpha =(\alpha_k:k=1,2,3,4)$ is a basis of $V$.

You can then write out the **matrix** representation of $f$ with respect to the basis  $\alpha$ of $V$ and the standard basis of $W$. Then you can work with the representation matrix by standard procedures.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
$$f(x)=f\left(\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\delta\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}\right)=$$
$$=\alpha f\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\beta f\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\gamma f\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}+\delta f\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The input matrices form a basis of $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$.

Write $v\in\Bbb R^{2\times2}$ as $a_1\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+a_4\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $v\in\ker f\iff f(v)=0_{\Bbb R^{2\times3}}$ i.e.$$a_1\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}3&3&5\\3&3&5\end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}+a_4\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$from where you get the three independent equations$$a_1+3a_2+a_3+a_4=0\\2a_1+3a_2+a_3=0\\3a_1+5a_2+a_3+a_4=0$$yielding $v=a_1\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and $\ker f=\text{Span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the standard bases of$\mathcal M_2(\mathbf R)$
and $\mathcal M_{2\times 3}(\mathbf R)$::
$$E_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace E_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace E_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\1&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace E_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\0&1\end{bmatrix} $$
$$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 &0 \\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\enspace e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 &0 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, \cdots$$
The matrix of the linear map $f$ is
$$T_f=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 2 & 0 & 1\\-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\-2 & 4 & 0 &1 \\ -2 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$
and, as it has obviously rank $\le 3$, you can simply consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 2 & 0 & 1\\-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\-2 & 4 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$
to determine the kernel, which can easily be done by row reduction.